# How to get multiple row values in single row but in different line(with Line break) in Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

here the above table is my input and the below table I need as output.

Answer (score 1):

A simple option is to aggregate them using `listagg` and set delimiter to the newline character:

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from temp;

WO TITLE
-- --------------------
W1 T1
W1 T2
W2 TT1
```

Query:

```
SQL> select workflow_id,
  2    listagg(title, chr(10)) within group (order by title) as title
  3  from temp
  4  group by workflow_id;

WO TITLE
-- --------------------
W1 T1
   T2

W2 TT1

SQL>
```

Comment: No its not working for me.

Comment: It should. Which tool do you use? If it is SQL Developer, run that piece of code as a **script** (F5).

Answer (score 1):

Use `LISTAGG` with a new line separator (assuming that you have already ordered your rows):

```sql
SELECT workflow_id,
       LISTAGG(title, CHR(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS titles
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY workflow_id;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (workflow_id, title) AS
SELECT 'W1', 'd1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'W1', 'd5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'W1', 'd4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'W2', 'd2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'W2', 'd3' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | WORKFLOW_ID | TITLES |
> | --- | --- |
> | W1 | d1 d5 d4 |
> | W2 | d2 d3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e04f319b91186e905b4e71e9582f4f5e)*

Answer (score 0):

This works here, hopefully it could help...

```
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select 'w1' "WORKFLOW_NO", 'd1' "DISCIPLINE" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 'w1' "WORKFLOW_NO", 'd5' "DISCIPLINE" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 'w1' "WORKFLOW_NO", 'd4' "DISCIPLINE" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 'w2' "WORKFLOW_NO", 'd2' "DISCIPLINE" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 'w2' "WORKFLOW_NO", 'd3' "DISCIPLINE" From Dual
        )
SELECT
    SUBSTR(LISTAGG(' ' || Chr(10) || WORKFLOW_NO) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY WF), 3, 50)  "WORKFLOW_NO",
    LISTAGG(DISCIPLINE, Chr(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY WF) "DISCIPLINE"
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            c.WORKFLOW_NO "WF",
            c.CNT "CNT",
            CASE 
              WHEN Count(1) OVER(PARTITION BY t.WORKFLOW_NO ORDER BY t.WORKFLOW_NO ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) = c.CNT 
              THEN t.WORKFLOW_NO 
            ELSE '' 
            END "WORKFLOW_NO",
            t.DISCIPLINE "DISCIPLINE"
        FROM
            tbl t
        INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                  WORKFLOW_NO "WORKFLOW_NO",
                  Count(WORKFLOW_NO) OVER(PARTITION BY WORKFLOW_NO ORDER BY WORKFLOW_NO) "CNT"
                FROM
                  tbl
            ) c ON(c.WORKFLOW_NO = t.WORKFLOW_NO)
    )
GROUP BY
    WF, CNT
--
--  R e s u l t
--  WORKFLOW_NO   DISCIPLINE    
--  ------------  ----------    
--                d1     
--                d4      
--  w1            d5 
--  -----------------------------------------
--                d2    
--  w2            d3
```

Comment: To get Workflow aligned with  the last Discipline there are space and Chr(10) infront of and concatenated to the Workflow. The leading space and Chr(10) are removed by Substring function. Didn't check but there probably is an extra trailing Chr(10) in Discipline which could be removed too. The count(*) proves that there are 2 records. Regards...